# Mellanox adapter on GCP instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mellanox

I'm trying to install MOFED on an instance (preferably with a GPU) and was wondering if anyone knows if a Mellanox adapter is available at any Google Cloud Platform VM. The VM instances that I've been spinning up come with a Virtio network card that is not recognized by the MOFED installer. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you install a Mellanox-specific OFED implementation on a machine that doesn't have Mellanox hardware?

Comment: I'm doing some testing and the standard OFED drivers weren't working for me. The installation completed but the (MPI) software was bailing out with a bunch of error messages. Just trying to figure out if there is any combination of hardware/software able to handle some codes.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using virtual hardware on your VM, the only adapter is Virtio by default on all instances.